# PHPUnit Class not found even though it is defined

Tags: php, function, unit-testing, class, phpunit

I'm trying to unit-test my class-function using PHPUnit, but I keep running into `Class not found` error, even though it is present.

Here's my `func.php` where the class is defined:

```
<?php
class func {
    public function url($var) {
        //do something
        return myvalue;
    }

?>
```

And here's `funcCase.php` where the Test class is defined:

```
<?php
require 'func.php';
require 'PHPUnit.php';


class funcTest extends PHPUnit_TestCase {
    // contains the object handle of the string class
    var $box;

    // constructor of the test suite
    function funcTest($name) {
       $this->PHPUnit_TestCase($name);
    }

    // called before the test functions will be executed
    // this function is defined in PHPUnit_TestCase and overwritten
    // here
    function setUp() {
        // create a new instance of String with the
        // string 'abc'
        $this->box = new func();
    }

    // called after the test functions are executed
    // this function is defined in PHPUnit_TestCase and overwritten
    // here
    function tearDown() {
        // delete your instance
        unset($this->box);
    }

    // test the url
    function testurl() {
        $result = $this->box->url('myvalue');
        $expected = 'myvalue';
        echo $result;
        $this->assertTrue($result == $expected);

    }

}
?>
```

And the `funcTest.php` which runs the PHPTestSuite:

```
<?php

require_once 'funcCase.php';
require_once 'PHPUnit.php';

$suite  = new PHPUnit_TestSuite("funcTest");
$result = PHPUnit::run($suite);

echo $result -> toString();
?>
```

When running the `funcTest.php` using `phpunit funcTest.php` I get this error:

```
TestCase funcTest->testurl() failed: expected TRUE, actual FALSE  
Class 'funcTest' could not be found in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\funcTest.php'.
```

Why am I getting this if the `funcTest` class is defined and `funcCase.php` is included in `funcTest.php`?

Comment: `PHPUnit_TestCase` and `require_once 'PHPUnit.php';` imply that you are trying to use PHPUnit 1.x which was released 20+ years ago for PHP 4. Are you sure you want/need to do that?

Comment: @SebastianBergmann No, not really, I downloaded and installed the latest PHPUnit and my PHP version is 8 which I installed using XAMPP. Could you give an example to use the modern PHPUnit in my case?

Comment: Even PHP code itself uses some really outdated practices. Are you following an old tutorial or something?